# IE8 print preview displaying blank space in between contents

Tags: internet-explorer-8, print-preview

In IE 8 print preview page page displaying space between contents.
original html file don't have any space between contents.
There is no `<br>` tag also.please refer the image for reference.
Mozilla shows = 6 page ,IE shows = 9 page.
Any one came across this strange problem??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Title says IE9; tag says IE8? Which one is the problem (or is it all versions?)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the link which you are trying to view?

Try adding following in your print CSS file

```
<link  
    href="http://www.your-domain.com/css/print.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css" 
    media="print" />
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, 
h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, 
cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, 
small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, 
ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, 
tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, 
canvas, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, 
hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time, mark, 
audio, video, container {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    background:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Added like below for print css,Print preview itself showing problems in the screen.<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print file path" media="print" id="printStylesheet" />

Answer (score 0):

In my office project I had a chance to create a print preview page. When I designing it I had to test it in IE8, IE9, FF, Safari and chrome. I faced many issues when designing that page for several browsers. Most of the time alignment issues occurred due to CSS(I mean for the print page). If IE see a pagebreak in css there will be a lot of gap. Also due to floating elements. So you ahve to check the CSS and HTML structure is perfect. Also follow the below guides.

1. [Guide 1](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/a/aa042103a.htm)
2. [Guide 2](http://webdesign.about.com/od/printerfriendly/a/aa041403a.htm)